# Minibrick8 doesnt connect to computer via RS-232 serial cable when there is a Snap-action-switch (microswitch) attatched

Tags: robotics, dmx512

I am using a MiniBrick8 (from Gilderfluke & Company in Burbank, California), as part of a lighting/ projector rig. The MiniBrick8 needs an input from a button (using a switch) to start a program running (PCMacs). At the moment the MiniBrick8 is also connected to a BrightSign Media Player.

Minibrick8 doesnt connect to computer via RS-232 serial cable when there is a Snap-action-switch (microswitch) attatched and drawing power from the '9-24 VDC' screw output.

The switch has two output parts: NC, NO, and a power input (COM). (NC and NO being normally closed and normally open respectively).

The NC is connected to ground, so when the switch is not pressed down power is routed directly from the VDC through the switch into ground. Then when the button is pressed power is instead routed from the switch into the MiniBrick8's A-input.

I then take the A-inputs return cable and ground it.

Maybe the fact that while the switch is not pressed down current is constantly flowing through the switch into ground? Is this a problem?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED:

It was perhaps as I thought.

I changed the switch to get a power input into the NO (normally open) connector, leaving the NC (normally closed) connector without any cable attached, connecting the output via the COM connector to one of the A-trigger/input terminals (the other going to ground).

I had previously thought (incorrectly obviously) that all the switch's connectors had to have wires connecting them to something.

Here is a source: [YouTube Video: https://youtu.be/pf_Mngbx32w](https://youtu.be/pf_Mngbx32w)

^^ This helped me figure it out.